# Does Ruby's gsub not treat \n as a whitespace character?

Tags: json, ruby, gsub

I'm trying to perform a simple operation - turn some input text into JSON, process it, and use it further.

```
require 'json'

aws_region = "us-east-1"

tag = `sudo aws ec2 describe-tags --region="#{aws_region}" --
filters "Name=resource-type,Values=instance" "Name=key,Values=Group" 
"Name=resource-id,Values=$(ec2metadata --instance-id)"`

puts tag

tag_json = tag.to_json.gsub(/\s+/, "")
#tag_json = tag.gsub("\n", "")

puts tag_json

obj = JSON.parse(tag_json)

desired_value = obj["Tags"][0]["Value"]

puts desired_value
```

I expected the above to strip out all whitespace including newlines, but to my surprise, the output still has newlines in it. The JSON.parse fails with the below error because the newlines are still present. With the additional tag_json assignment above uncommented, it removes the newlines and succeeds.

```
JSON::ParserError
-----------------
746: unexpected token at '"{\n\"Tags\": [\n{\n\"ResourceType\": 
\"instance\", \n\"ResourceId\": \"i-XXXXXX\", \n\"Value\": 
\"groupA\", \n\"Key\": \"Group\"\n}\n]\n}\n"'
```

I end up having to have a separate case for newlines. Why does gsub treat newline characters as non-whitespace? Is there any other expression that will combine all of whitespace, tabs and newlines so I can strip them out?

Comment: What specifically is in `tag`? What ends up in `tag_json`? Are you sure you're using `tag_json`? `gsub(/\s+/, '')` should remove newlines so something is going on that you're not showing us, a minimal example would be useful for everyone. BTW, there's nothing wrong with newlines (or other whitespace) in JSON.

Comment: Tag is what you see there, but in plain text form before. I'll add a more complete example to the original post.

Comment: Updated original post with full context. As you can see, it's not much different.

Comment: `gsub(/\s+/,"")` will replace newlines. Perhaps you have literal `\n` (two characters) rather than the actual `\n` (single character)?

Comment: [Demo](http://rubular.com/r/SVjRyvIfjT) (Click 'Show Invisibles')

Comment: Try `tag_json.gsub(/[\s\p{]/, '')` - also, you don't need the `+` in the regex because `gsub` will match every occurence anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's an encoding issue. Try `tag_json = tag.to_json.gsub(/[\s\p{]/, "")`

You don't need the `+` in your expression because `gsub` removes all occurrences of a single character anyway.

Consider `"aaaaaa".gsub(/a/, '') # => ""`

Comment: This worked for me, so I suspect an encoding issue was at fault. I was running this from a Chef cookbook which makes it seem likely it was something like that.